# How to interprete this でも?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0202.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-closeup_002

The sentence in question:
 ところが、八王子隕石の存在は、落下場所となった八王子市内でもほとんど知られていません。

My attempt at translation:
"However, concerning the existence of hachioji meteorite, (the place) in hachioji inner city which became the impact site is practically not known."

I don't know whether I should interprete でも in sense of でも or で+も (で being either the copula or the particle). I settled for the solution visible in my translation where で is the particle indicating location. But this was basically just because I couldnt come up with a better solution ^^

Comment: Yes, it's locative で with も (even).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 落下場所となった八王子市内**で**+**も**
>
> = 落下場所となった八王子市内**で**+**すら**

If you swap も for すら and the sentence still makes sense, も does serve as an intensifier "even".

でも in the sense of "though / encore que / obwohl / anche se", on the other hand, is usually placed at the beginning of a sentence (followed by a comma) to introduce a concessive subordinate clause, as in:

> 僕はこの歌手のファンだ。**でも**、ライブを見に行きたいほどではない。